# IronRuby REPL with required .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, console, ironruby, read-eval-print-loop

What is the best way to put together a "shortcut" to launch a IronRuby REPL with some .NET assemblies preloaded? I think there is a way to do this in Powershell (via Snapin or Module) and I'm looking for something similar in IronRuby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a bat file that executes

ir -S irb -r irb/completion -r bin/Assembly1.dll -r bin/Assembly2.dll

Comment: Thanks Jim. Seems simple enough. +1&answer

Comment: How would you pre-instantiate some objects too. Like a xd = System.Xml.Document ? Do you put these after the first line in the bat file? I couldn't get this way to work.

Comment: You could use the -e parameter or create a ruby file and put those in there. I prefer the ruby file then you can do: 
ir -S irb -r irb/completion -r bin/Assembly1.dll -r lib/initializer.rb